# How to avoid highly concurrency update primary key error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code was a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008:

```
select @pkvalue = maxkey + 1, @id = id
from dbo.sys_maxkey
where tablename = UPPER(@tablename) and keyname = UPPER(@fieldname) and ds_id = @ds_id   

update dbo.sys_maxkey with (updlock)
set maxkey = maxkey + 1
where id = @id
```

This code is gets a primary key, it finds max key from a table stored all table's max primary key, but it has a problem, when the concurrency is high, maybe two people all more would read a row by the same time (even we add uplock), and and the same value update and insert data, it makes error, how to avoid it?

Comment: Why not use a PK with auto generated sequence number instead?

Comment: 1.When you want to import data from other database,the auto generate PK will conflict.    2.When you want to insert data by hand,it makes trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the value with exclusive lock in the `select`:

```
select @pkvalue=maxkey+1,@id=i
from dbo.sys_maxkey with (xlock)
where tablename=UPPER(@tablename) and keyname=UPPER(@fieldname) and ds_id=@ds_id
```

You will need to put both statements (reading and updating) into one transaction.

This will block the second process from even reading the value until the first process is done with the transaction.

Comment: `declare @id int
  select @pkvalue= maxkey+1, @id= id from sys_maxkey with (xlock)  --  x lock
             where tablename=upper(@tablename)and keyname=upper(@fieldname) and ds_id= @ds_id
  
 update sys_maxkey with (xlock) -- x lock
  set maxkey= maxkey + 1 where id =@id`  like this?

Comment: You don't need an xlock on update, I think. It's not forbidden to use transactions.